# SMD Q1 Transistor ID request from image

Tags: transistors, identification

Burned-out transistor on external drive reader.  Marked A1DA. Would like to find a substitution, please. [image: Fried transistor Q1]

Comment: Are you sure that is a "D"? It looks more like an "0"

Comment: It looks like a zero, but I did not find something.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a MOSFET and the three solder connections at the bottom left are possibly a hollow bushing. So this will be a P-channel MOSFET to stop the current flow from this DC-jack.

But possibly the dimension of this MOSFET was never right, if the error does not occur because of a short circuit, then you should use an other, bigger P-channel MOSFET to replace this one. You can do this with three wires and put the bigger MOSFET on a free place bottom up (death bug method) and with free wiring.